# How to update a ViewModel class variable when ApplicationData settings have changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, win-universal-app

The code below fires every time that I click a button. It works, but I realize that I shouldn't check for the sound state and volume every time that I play a sound. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the ViewModel to update the ApplicationData any other way. I have a Settings ViewModel which sets the sound state using a toggleswitch, and a slider for the volume.

Ideally, I think, the ViewModel would update the class variables when it is navigated back to, or the Settings ViewModel would call an update method in this ViewModel. But I can't seem to get it to work except for updating it in the PlaySound method.

```
public object localSettingSoundState;
public object localSoundVolumeSetting;
ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;


    public void PlaySound(MediaElement mediaElementName)
    {
        localSettingSoundState = localSettings.Values["localSoundSetting"];
        MediaElementVolume = Convert.ToDouble(localSettings.Values["localSoundVolumeSetting"]);

        if (localSettingSoundState.ToString() != "false")
        {
            mediaElementName.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have not provided enough information for anyone to help you solve the problem. Your description is vague to the reader and you did not provide the ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I need to share a behavior between multiple viewmodels (here, your behavior is "storing and retrieving settings), I implement a "service". In your case, it could look like:

```
public class SettingsService
{
    private readonly ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

    private double? localSoundVolume;

    public double LocalSoundVolume
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.localSoundVolume == null)
            {
                this.localSoundVolume = Convert.ToDouble(localSettings.Values["localSoundVolumeSetting"])
            }

            return this.localSoundVolume;
        }

        set
        {
            this.localSoundVolume = value;
            localSettings.Values["localSoundVolumeSetting"] = value;
        }       
    }
}
```

Then you just need to register your service as a singleton and retrieve it in your viewmodels. Ideally you can do that by using dependency injection, but if no IoC mechanism is provided by whatever MVVM framework you're using then a service locator can do the job. From there, it's just a matter of setting the `SettingsService.LocalSoundVolume` property from your SettingsViewModel and reading it from your other viewmodels. Since the value is cached, you will be retrieving it from the ApplicationData settings only once.

Following this pattern, you should be able to remove all references to ApplicationData from your viewmodels.

Comment: KooKiz, that was perfect! Thank you. So, I did exactly what you suggested. I created a Service using the code above, added a Singleton, added the code for the localSettingSoundState, removed all of the ApplicationData code from my ViewModels, added a reference to the Singleton (Services.SettingsService settingServices = Services.SettingsService.Instance;), and set the values in my ViewModels where needed (e.g. settingServices.LocalSoundVolume = sliderValue;).!!!